# Selecting Single XML from Multiple XMLs rows in a Table

Tags: sql, xml

I have an XML column in a table where each row of the table is a complete XML node.  I am trying to simply trying to select a subset of these rows and generate an XML document out of it with a root node.  I thought I could do the following, but it keeps added an extra wrapper around each node with the name of the XML column.  Is there anything different I can do to not get this wrapper?

Sample Data Structure:

```
CREATE TABLE ActivityTable 
(
    XMLDATA AS XML
)

INSERT INTO [ActivityTable] VALUES ( '<Activity>This is activity one</Activity>' )
INSERT INTO [ActivityTable] VALUES ( '<Activity>This is activity two</Activity>' )
INSERT INTO [ActivityTable] VALUES ( '<Activity>This is activity three</Activity>' )
```

Query to get Data

```
SELECT 
    XMLdata FROM ActivityTable 
FOR XML PATH(''), ROOT('RootNode')
```

What I'm getting:

```
<root>
  <XMLdata>
    <Activity>This is activity one</Activity>
  </XMLdata>
  <XMLdata>
    <Activity>This is activity two</Activity>
  </XMLdata>
  <XMLdata>
    <Activity>This is activity three</Activity>
  </XMLdata>
</root>
```

What I want:

```
<root>
  <Activity>This is activity one</Activity>
  <Activity>This is activity two</Activity>
  <Activity>This is activity three</Activity>
</root>
```

Comment: Is there a reason why you can't name the column 'Activity' and remove the tags from the column data?

Comment: Yes, the data above is just a sample and the actual data has attributes on the outer node.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT XMLdata AS '*' 
FROM ActivityTable 
FOR XML PATH(''), ROOT('RootNode')
```

[Columns with a Name Specified as a Wildcard Character](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb500154.aspx)

> If the column name specified is a wildcard character (*), the content
>   of that column is inserted as if there is no column name specified.

Answer (score 1):

using `.query('/Node')` is a way of querying for a certain node, and you don't get the XMLData tags back. Hope it helps!

```
SELECT XMLDATA.query('/Activity') FROM ActivityTable 
FOR XML PATH(''), ROOT('root')
```

[SQL Fiddle example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/93efc/24)